# Abort a request after checking response headers

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I have a script that requests a URL via `urllib.request`'s `urlopen` and then gets it's `info()`.

I don't want to proceed with the request after I've got these headers so I'm currently just leaving it as it is and forgetting about it, but this seems like I'm leaving the connection open and perhaps the server is sending more that just gets ignored.

How can I abort the request properly?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import urllib.request

response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://google.co.uk')
headers = dict(response.info())
print(headers)
# now finished with response, abort???
# ... more stuff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is a `HEAD` request. Something like

```
>>> import httplib
>>> c = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.google.co.uk")
>>> c.request("HEAD", "/index.html")
>>> r = c.getresponse()
>>> r.getheaders()
[('x-xss-protection', '1; mode=block'), ('transfer-encoding', 'chunked'), ('set-cookie', 'PREF=ID=7867b0a5641d5f7b:FF=0:TM=1363882090:LM=1363882090:S=EXLl2JgBqzMKODcq; expires=Sat, 21-Mar-2015 16:08:10 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.co.uk, NID=67=qElAph6eqHyYKbh995ivP4B-21YRDRED4-uRXx0AvC3vLpv0SF1LkdsI2k6Hg1IhsatrVVqWf2slcMCaQsAZwZ89YfU0F1iPVBdt9PC2FItff31oRJ3gvhJVTQLa_RAt; expires=Fri, 20-Sep-2013 16:08:10 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.co.uk; HttpOnly'), ('expires', '-1'), ('server', 'gws'), ('cache-control', 'private, max-age=0'), ('date', 'Thu, 21 Mar 2013 16:08:10 GMT'), ('p3p', 'CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."'), ('content-type', 'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'), ('x-frame-options', 'SAMEORIGIN')]
>>>
```

From [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)

> The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT
>   return a message-body in the response. The metainformation contained
>   in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical
>   to the information sent in response to a GET request. This method can
>   be used for obtaining metainformation about the entity implied by the
>   request without transferring the entity-body itself. This method is
>   often used for testing hypertext links for validity, accessibility,
>   and recent modification.
>
> The response to a HEAD request MAY be cacheable in the sense that the
>   information contained in the response MAY be used to update a
>   previously cached entity from that resource. If the new field values
>   indicate that the cached entity differs from the current entity (as
>   would be indicated by a change in Content-Length, Content-MD5, ETag or
>   Last-Modified), then the cache MUST treat the cache entry as stale.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted. I also took a look through `/Lib/http/client.py` and it looks like there is also a method on `HTTPResponse` named `close` which called `self.fp.close()` which I might decide to use if a HEAD request isn't working for some URIs.

Comment: ` The metainformation contained in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical to the information sent in response to a GET request. ` Note the wording SHOULD is not MUST. There are plenty of websites that lie about the content type to try and avoid being scraped.